# Re-fetching parent 'currentUser' data after child component logs in using Apollo

Tags: reactjs, jwt, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm using apollo-client and connecting to an express server using that's using express-jwt for authentication via the header.  My current client side components look like this: `App -> Login`.

Here's what my client side initialization file looks like (`index.js`).  I've omitted unnecessary code for brevity:

```
const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : null
    }
  };
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(new HttpLink({ uri: '/graphql' })),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

That's basically setting up Apollo middleware that checks for a `token` in localStorage and adds it to the header on each subsequent request so that my logged in user can be authenticated.  Here's my top-level `App` component (which is using react-router v4 - irrelevant code ommited):

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const { currentUser } = this.props.data;
    console.log(currentUser);

    return (
       <Switch>
          <Route
            path="/login"
            render={routeProps => <Login {...routeProps} {...this.props} />}
          />
        </Switch>
    );
  }
}

export default graphql(currentUserQuery, {
  options: { fetchPolicy: 'network-only' }
})(withRouter(App));
```

As you might guess, when my `App` component is created it calls the `currentUserQuery` to retrieve the current user from my graphql endpoint.  Here's the relevant code for my `Login` component:

```
class Login extends Component {
  handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.props
      .mutate({
        variables: { email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password }
      })
      .then(result => {
        const { jwt } = result.data.login;
        if (jwt) {
          localStorage.setItem('token', jwt);
          this.props.history.push('/');
          return;
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.message);
      });
  };
}

export default graphql(userLoginMutation)(Login);
```

My problem is that once my `userLoginMutation` succeeds, I'd like to route back to my `App` component and expect to see my `currentUser` object there.  Unfortunately the `App` component does not trigger a new graphql query to attempt to get the `currentUser` object when I route back to it.  I also tried to use Apollo's `refetchQueries` method on the login mutation to try and refetch the current user, but that runs the query before the login promise is finished and the token is not yet in the middleware, so the request does nothing.  It's worth noting that if I simply do a hard refresh on the page, I get access to my `currentUser` object because it is pulling the token from `localStorage` and placing it in the middleware properly.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: In my opinion, the App component does not have to trigger a new graphql query to get the credentials info. I would get the token from the server and store them in global variables that would be accessible among my application. Then, when routing to your App component, you can import your credentials variables and work with them. You can use the same logic as the one described here : https://www.howtographql.com/react-apollo/5-authentication/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need a way to trigger the only refetch after localStorage is updated, but before you navigate away. Here's one way to do that: Wrap your `Login` component with another HOC for the `currentUser` query:

```
export default compose(
  graphql(userLoginMutation),
  graphql(currentUserQuery),
)(MyComponent)
```

Now your component's props will include both `mutate` and `data`, so we can do something like:

```
this.props.mutate({
  variables: { email: this.state.email, password:this.state.password}
})
  .then(result => {
    const { jwt } = result.data.login;
    if (jwt) {
      localStorage.setItem('token', jwt);
      return this.props.data.refetch()
    }
    // if there's no jwt, we still want to return a Promise although
    // you could do Promise.reject() instead and trigger the catch
    return Promise.resolve();
  })
  .then(() => this.props.history.push('/'))
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error.message);
  });
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just add `refetchQueries: ['currentUserQuery']` to the `mutate` parameters?